# How to Update MongoDB doc in golang coming from React Client?

Tags: mongodb, go

Excuse the long newb post but I am not really sure what to ask here. I am trying to 'save' a document in MongoDB. The document is created via collection.InsertOne(), allowing MongoDB to create the _id field. But I can't figure out how to update the document after that.

The document is sent by the golang back end to a react client. The user then edits some fields and hits save.

I tried this:

```
filter := bson.D{}
result, err := sequencesCollection.ReplaceOne(c, filter, document)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

It keeps telling me that the document's _id has changed:

> write exception: write errors: [After applying the update, the (immutable) field '_id' was found to have been altered to _id: "64d50067a145130ccf0521af"]

I think I am messing up the _id field somehow. I get the document like this:

```
func getSequence(ctx *gin.Context) {
id := ctx.Params.ByName("id")

_id, err := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(id)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

var sequence bson.M
if err := sequencesCollection.FindOne(ctx, bson.M{"_id": _id}).Decode(&sequence); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Printf("the sequence: %s", sequence)

ctx.JSON(http.StatusOK, sequence)
}
```

Seems to work. I can see the the _id field is an ObjectID

> the sequence: map[_id:ObjectID("64d50067a145130ccf0521af") currentEnvelopeId: currentPanelId:ARP deviceFamilyId:Mini/Monologue division:%!s(float64=8) envelopes:[] length:%!s(float64=3) midiDevicePreferences:map[inputs:[] outputs:[]] midiSettings:map[midiInputChannelNum:%!s(float64=-1) midiInputDeviceId: midiInputDeviceName:omni midiOutputChannelNum:%!s(float64=0) midiOutputDeviceId: midiOutputDeviceName:none midiRemoteChannelNum:%!s(float64=-1) midiRemoteDeviceId:] name:New Sequence numSteps:%!s(float64=3) packs:[] playOrder:forward rawSteps:[map[gateLength:%!s(float64=0.5) note:%!s(float64=60) velocity:%!s(float64=100)] map[gateLength:%!s(float64=0.5) note:%!s(float64=60) velocity:%!s(float64=100)] map[gateLength:%!s(float64=0.5) note:%!s(float64=72) velocity:%!s(float64=100)]] scaleSettings:map[customNotes:[] root:%!s(float64=0) scaleType:Chromatic] searchHints:map[] skin:map[backgroundColor:%!s(float64=1.671168e+07) velocityColor:%!s(float64=1.5598465e+07)] stepFilters:[] steps:[map[gateLength:%!s(float64=0.5) note:%!s(float64=60) velocity:%!s(float64=100)] map[gateLength:%!s(float64=0.5) note:%!s(float64=60) velocity:%!s(float64=100)] map[gateLength:%!s(float64=0.5) note:%!s(float64=72) velocity:%!s(float64=100)]] sysexPresetAddress:map[packId:localpack presetId:0 typeId:sysex] tempo:%!s(float64=120) user_id:62d93722d51a8f9b6685d3f6 user_name: viewSettings:map[]]

I am trying to put the document like this:

```
func putSequence(c *gin.Context) {
jsonData, err := io.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)
fmt.Printf("jsonData: %s\n", jsonData)

var document bson.M = bson.M{}
err = json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &document)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

_id := document["_id"]
filter := bson.D{{Key: "_id", Value: _id}}
result, err := sequencesCollection.ReplaceOne(c, filter, document)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

c.JSON(http.StatusOK, result.UpsertedCount)
}
```

I post the original document like this:

```
func postSequence(c *gin.Context) {
jsonData, err := io.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)

var document bson.M = bson.M{}
err = json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &document)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

result, err := sequencesCollection.InsertOne(c, document)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

c.JSON(http.StatusOK, result.InsertedID)
}
```

I guess my question is ... how do I preserve the _id field when going to the client and back via json? Or just, how do I replace the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working as a MongoDB AppService function and then converted it to go.

I couldn't get it to work without having to manually fix the _id field. Would love to know of a cleaner way.

```
func putSequence(c *gin.Context) {
jsonData, err := io.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)

var document bson.M
err = bson.UnmarshalExtJSON(jsonData, true, &document)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// fix _id
var hexId HexId
err = bson.UnmarshalExtJSON(jsonData, true, &hexId)
_id, err := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(hexId.ID.Hex())
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
document["_id"] = hexId.ID

result, err := sequencesCollection.ReplaceOne(c, bson.M{"_id": _id}, document)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Printf("Modified %d document(s)\n", result.ModifiedCount)
c.JSON(http.StatusOK, result.UpsertedCount)
}
```

Here is the MongoDB 'AppService' function:

```
exports = async function(payload, response) {
console.log(`hi from PutSequence. Payload:\n${JSON.stringify(payload)}`)

if (payload.body) {
  const sequences = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas").db("Powermad").collection("sequences");

  const body =  EJSON.parse(payload.body.text());
  console.log(`Parsed body:\n${JSON.stringify(body)}`)
  body._id = BSON.ObjectId(body._id);
  return await sequences.updateOne({_id: body._id }, body);
}

return  {};
};
```